# How to pull tweet using twitter url in python

Tags: python, twitter

I have a twitter url ("http://twitter.com/1/statuses/860392275108548608") and I need to fetch the tweet using this URL.

I checked some python packages like twitter, tweepy, etc. Here there are functions to pull tweets for particular account and hashtags, but I could find any function to pull from URL.

Can someone please share the function to pull the tweet using url.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use an HTML parsing library. It's not the best way to do it, but it will work. What you'll have to do is find a similarity in class or id that every tweet shares. You'll then get the text of that tweet by finding the textual value of the element.